# TMDB API PHP - Show All and Genre

Tags: php, api

```
<?php
$ca = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=5094e4539de46c1abd1461920f3a3fb9");
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($ca);
curl_close($ca);
//var_dump($response);
$config = json_decode($response, true);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/106646-the-wolf-of-wall-street?api_key=5094e4539de46c1abd1461920f3a3fb9");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);

//print_r($result);

$x=0; 
while($x<=0)
  {
  echo("<a href=\"#\"><img src='" . $config['images']['base_url'] . $config['images']['poster_sizes'][1] . $result['results'][$x]['poster_path'] . "'/></a>");
  echo (" ". $result['results'][$x]['title'] . "<br/>");
  echo ("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.themoviedb.org/\">TMDb</a> ".         $result['results'][$x]['vote_average'] . "/10 <br/>");
  echo (" ". $result['results'][$x]['release_date']);
  echo (" ". $result['results'][$x]['genre']);
  $x++;
  }


?>
```

I am trying to show 'The Wolf Of Wall Streets' information. This is not working and I am not too sure how to get it working Ive had a look around and it's all just a bit too confusing. Please help.

I would also like to have a page where you can select a category and then the films within that category show up (limited to 15 per page)
If anyone can help me with that I will say thank you. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need the title of the movie in your API call. You can do like this :

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/106646?api_key=5094e4539de46c1abd1461920f3a3fb9
```

This call return informations from 1 movie, so you don't need a `while` loop do display these informations :

```
echo ("<a href=\"#\"><img src='" . $config['images']['base_url'] . $config['images']['poster_sizes'][1] . $result['poster_path'] . "'/></a>");
echo (" ". $result['title'] . "<br/>");
echo ("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.themoviedb.org/\">TMDb</a> ".         $result['vote_average'] . "/10 <br/>");
echo (" ". $result['release_date']);
echo (" ". $result['genre']);
```

For your list, first build a genre list with there IDs :

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=5094e4539de46c1abd1461920f3a3fb9
```

Then list your movies :

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/28/movies?api_key=5094e4539de46c1abd1461920f3a3fb9&page_size=2
```

Instead of a `while` loop, you can do a `foreach` like this :

```
foreach ($results as $movie) {
    echo '<li>'.$movie['title'].'</li>
}
```

You can find all details about the TMDB API here :
http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/reference/genres/genreidmovies/